# What is the most effective way to approach resetting a reactive angular form?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I have [Reactive Form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview) inputs (`mdInput`) that is initialized in the following manner using `FormBuilder`:

```
contactForm: FormGroup;

this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(128)]],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  subject: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(128)]],
  message: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(1000)]]
});

onSubmit(): void {
  this.resetForm();
}

private resetForm(): void {
  this.contactForm.reset();
}
```

With Angular Material inputs associated to the respective FormControl elements with hooking into `(ngSubmit)`:

```
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
  </md-input-container>

  <button type="submit" md-raised-button [disabled]="contactForm.invalid">Submit</button>
```

When calling `reset()` on the `FormGroup` `contactForm` (this.contactForm.reset()`, the form elements values are successfully cleared/replaced with empty strings, but the elements are both immediately dirty and touched with CSS classes`ng-invalid`&&`ng-touched`present on the elements. Strangely they also have the`ng-pristine`CSS class on them after the`reset()`.

What is the most effective way to approach resetting the form including clearing/resetting the `FormControl` values and marking them as not touched and not dirty? Is it utilizing `markAsUntouched()` or `markAsPristine()`? Is it using `setValue()` or `reset()` with specific options? The goal is to reset the form as if the user is interacting with it for the first time.

**Update:** Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrrrqy) showing this issue in action.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: It should not be the case. According to the source-code, `reset` will mark the form as untouched and pristine. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1087

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrrrqy) to demonstrate the issue in action. You'll notice that onSubmit calls the reset(), causing all the inputs, which have `Validators` to be touched and dirty. Thanks!

Comment: Somehow using `ngSubmit` disrupts the flow. I can see all inputs untouched + pristine but the errors are still showing. If you change the submit button to something like `<button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()"` it will works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Harry Ninh in the comments, using a regular button instead of `ngSubmit` will fix the behavior. This is because, by default, Material errors show when an input is `invalid` and either `touched` or `submitted`. There is a long thread about it [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4190), but basically, calling `reset()` on a form control or form group does not reset the actual form, just the values.

You can do one of the following:

1. Use the workaround mentioned by @Harry Ninh
2. Use `ViewChild` to get access to the [`FormGroupDirective`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective) and reset it.

See here:

```
@ViewChild(FormGroupDirective) myForm;

contactForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.createForm();
}

private createForm(): void {
  this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(128)]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    subject: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(128)]],
    message: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(1000)]]
  });
}

onSubmit(): void {
  this.resetForm();
}

private resetForm(): void {
  if (this.myForm) {
    this.myForm.resetForm();
  }
}
```